# The bold styles in `$\mathbf{\mathrm{x}}^*$ ` doesn't work

Tags: fonts, math-mode

The bold styles in `$\mathbf{\mathrm{x}}^*$` doesn't work. I was expecting to receive an upright, **bold** symbol **`x`**, but didn't. Why is this the case?

Comment: You don't need `\mathrm`.

Answer (score 14):

math font command in LaTeX, by design, do not combine properties the way text fonts do, each selects a specific alphabet , So your `\mathrm` completely hides the `\mathbf` just use `\mathbf{x}` to get a bold roman x.